# R - function which() that is not bringing the right output

Tags: r

I have a table temp1 that has 2 columns "Hospital.Name" and "heart attack" and 1 variable called "colname"

```
colname <- "heart attack"

Hospital.Name                      heart attack
ROUND ROCK MEDICAL CENTER           14.9  
CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER    12.0
```

I am trying to bring the record with the lowest "heart attack" number but I am getting an error on my formula it brings nothing, this is what I have:

```
temp1[which(temp1[[colname1]] == min(as.numeric(temp1[[colname1]]))),]
[1] Hospital.Name heart attack 
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

is bringing no results

but I know the right part of the formula is right because when I use

```
min(as.numeric(temp1[[colname1]]))
[1] 12
```

I get the min result of the "heart attack" column

Please help me with my formula:

```
temp1[which(temp1[[colname1]] == min(as.numeric(temp1[[colname1]]))),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then you want all the information against a row for which one of the variables has minimum value.

You can try `which.min` if this is what you want to do.

using mtcars data set present in R session:

```
mtcars[which.min(mtcars$mpg),]
```

Above will fetch record(row) which has minimum value of mpg field in mtcars data.

```
#> mtcars[which.min(mtcars$mpg),]
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.25 17.98  0  0    3    4
```

Now If you use `which` the way you have used in your dataset, you can have something like this:

```
mtcars[which(mtcars[[colname1]] == min(mtcars[[colname1]])),]
```

This will produce two records like below:

```
#> mtcars[which(mtcars[[colname1]] == min(mtcars[[colname1]])),]
#                     mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8  472 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8  460 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
```

**Moral of the story** `which.min` produces first instances of logical match, but `which` can give you both the instances of the match if there are multiple records of same minimum value.

From Documentation:

> Determines the location, i.e., index of the (first) minimum or maximum
>   of a numeric (or logical) vector.

In your case it might be something like:

```
temp1[which.min(temp1[,colname]) ,]
```

In case if its not in numeric, then rather doing lot of things in a step, break it for simplicity.

```
  temp1[,colname] <- as.numeric(temp1[,colname]) ##numeric conversion
  temp1[which.min(temp1[,colname]) ,]
```

where colname = "heart attack" as per your question

If you use below code you can have multiple records, also it seems ***you have written the right code*** , **your code is not working because you have a typo between colname and colname1**

```
temp1[which(temp1[[colname]] == min(temp1[[colname]])),]
```